# Is there in Geogebra an API to load an image

Tags: geogebra

In Geogebra you can insert an image interactively.
Is there any way to do this programmatically, i.e. just with a command, like **InsertImage** or **LoadImage**?
The construction protocol mentions only that the image was loaded without indicating the name of a relevant command or procedure.

Answer (score 0):

No way. This interface is not provided in the official version.
Unless you modify the source code, which is possible because ggb is open source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I just wanted to be sure. Sometimes you wonder why people insist on things that, at first sight, look counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

There *might* be a way... on https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:GeoGebra_Apps_API there is the entry

```
String setFileJSON(Object content)  [from ver 5.0]  Sets the current construction from a JSON (object or string) that includes XML and images (try getFileJSON for the precise format)
```

This implies that perhaps you could execute `api.getFileJSON()`, manipulate the resulting JSON to have the additional image you want, and then `api.setFileJSON` with the modified JSON. Not sure if it's worth that trouble to you, and **note** I have not tried this, so I am not certain it will work.

Comment: In addition, if you call console.log on the api object you get from deployggb.js (for example, as the argument to the appletOnLoad callback), you will see it has an undocumented method `addImage` -- you could try playing around with that. Not sure what parameters it takes or in what order, though, so you'd have to guess and see if you could get it working.